# Principled volume missing

Tags: node-editor

So I'm following a tutorial where the person adds a principled volume shader and I don't seem to have it and can't find it at all. I'm using blender 2.9 if that helps. Is there possibly anything I'm missing as it's confusing the heck out me

Comment: Well... For sure you are not using 2.9. Probably a typo, but - are you using 2.79 or 2.8?

Comment: Blender 2.9 doesn't exist. Principled volume is a new feature in 2.8 beta, it is not yet available in any official release

Comment: Sorry I mean 2.79 well the tutorial I'm using it says the person is using 2.79.3

Comment: 2.79 isn't the same as 2.79.3. This shader was included [in a commit](https://developer.blender.org/D3033) made on January 30, 2018, so you need this version or later. When in doubt, use the exact same version used in the tutorial.

Comment: yes but I cant seem to be able to get 2.79.3 as on blender its 2.79b , any sugestions where to get it ?

Comment: Make sure you are using Blender 2.8 (2.9 does not exist)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Blender 2.8 yet, you need to use the latest build of 2.79. You can download it here

https://builder.blender.org/download/

Unzip the package and start Blender directly from within the unpacked directory.